# INNER JOIN with GROUP_CONCAT returns repeating values

Tags: mysql

If I try to query my database with the following query, I get the intended result:

```
SELECT anime.anime, GROUP_CONCAT(themes.theme) AS themes
FROM anime
INNER JOIN anime_themes ON anime.id = anime_themes.anime_id
INNER JOIN themes ON themes.id = anime_themes.theme_id
GROUP BY anime.anime
ORDER BY anime.id;
```

**Example Output:**
"amnesia,bodyswitch,naturaldisaster,tragedy"

However, when I attempt to query more data at once using the following query, I get repeating data:

```
SELECT anime.*, directors.director, studios.studio, 
GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre) AS genres, GROUP_CONCAT(themes.theme) AS themes
FROM anime
INNER JOIN anime_directors ON anime.id = anime_directors.anime_id
INNER JOIN directors ON directors.id = anime_directors.director_id
INNER JOIN anime_studios ON anime.id = anime_studios.anime_id
INNER JOIN studios ON studios.id = anime_studios.studio_id
INNER JOIN anime_genres ON anime.id = anime_genres.anime_id
INNER JOIN genres ON genres.id = anime_genres.genre_id
INNER JOIN anime_themes ON anime.id = anime_themes.anime_id
INNER JOIN themes ON themes.id = anime_themes.theme_id
GROUP BY anime.anime
ORDER BY anime.id;
```

**Example Output:**
bodyswitch,naturaldisaster,tragedy,amnesia,bodyswitch,naturaldisaster,naturaldisaster,tragedy,amnesia,amnesia,bodyswitch,naturaldisaster,tragedy,tragedy,amnesia,bodyswitch"

The data doesn't even seem to be repeating in some coherent order with the second query. Why is the behavior different between the two queries, and how do I go about fixing this? Thanks.

Edit: Only 'themes' and 'genres' have repeating values while 'directors' and 'studios' don't, so I assume it has something to do with the GROUP_CONCAT function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add DISTINCT.

Example:

```
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genre) AS genres, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
 themes.theme) AS themes
```

Comment: Thanks! That solve my problem. Do you also happen to know why behavior is different between the two queries? The first query doesn't utilize distinct, but I get distinct results there.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining more table at second query, it may cause a record appear repeatedly.
Adding "DISTINCT" might remove the repeated values but that is not the best way to optimize this query.
You should also consider using subquery or left join.

Comment: The other tables that I'm joining don't have these records, so at what point would these records appear repeatedly?

Thanks for the advice. I've been trying to learn how to optimize my queries. I'll look into subqueries and the different join optimizations. Question though, would left join optimize this query and why? Are left join and inner join both based on the size of my 'anime' table?